# Gitlab API filter all projects by tag

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I was looking through the documentation on gitlab and couldn't find a way to filter out projects by tags. I do notice that if you go to the dashboard, then "Explore Projects", then "All", at the side "tags" appears which is a dropdown menu populated by all tags in the database, and when selecting one it allows you to filter the list.

As this is evidently available via gitlab, is there a way to request this via the API? Without the need to request all projects then manually iterate through them all to see if the tags match?

Comment: Did U tried https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/tags.html ???

Comment: Those are git tags, not project tags @SkorpEN

Comment: It looks like this is no longer in the UI anymore as you've described, but I believe you mean topical tags. For example: https://gitlab.com/explore/projects/topics/android

Answer (score 0):

project tags are listed in the project.tag_list field

Answer (score 0):

These "tags" are topics. For example you can search the "android" topic:

[image: topics]

This is the `topic` field when using the GitLab [list projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects).

For example to get the same results you might do something like this:

```
curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?topic=android
```